# Quartz CronScheduler running job multiple times

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I am using Quartz CronScheduler to execute a job every 15 minutes. Every time the job executes it checks the DB for any change in the cron expression and updates the job scheduler for the next run. I have implemented the above in the following way:

```
@Service
public class QuartzSchedulerService {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QuartzSchedulerService.class);

    private Scheduler           scheduler;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        try {
            scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
            scheduler.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Unable to start quartz scheduler", e);
        }
    }

    @PreDestroy
    private void destroy() {
        try {
            scheduler.shutdown();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Unable to shutdown quartz scheduler", e);
        }
    }

    public void registerCronJob(Class<? extends Job> jobClass, String cronExpression) {
        try {
            String jobName = jobClass.getSimpleName();
            CronScheduleBuilder cronBuilder = CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronExpression);
            JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(jobClass).withIdentity(jobName).build();
            CronTrigger cronTrigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity(jobName).withSchedule(cronBuilder).build();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, cronTrigger);
            LOG.info("Registered Cron Job:" + jobName + " " + jobDetail.getKey());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Unable to register cron job", e);
        }
    }

    public void updateCronSchedule(Class<? extends Job> jobClass, String cronExpression) {
        try {
            String jobName = jobClass.getSimpleName();
            CronScheduleBuilder cronBuilder = CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronExpression);
            CronTrigger newCronTrigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity(jobName).withSchedule(cronBuilder).build();
            scheduler.rescheduleJob(TriggerKey.triggerKey(jobName), newCronTrigger);
            LOG.info("Updated Cron Job:" + jobName + " " + newCronTrigger.getJobKey());
            LOG.info("Jobs executed: " + scheduler.getMetaData().getNumberOfJobsExecuted());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Unable to reschedule cron job", e);
        }
    }

}
```

The class which implements the Job interface is as belows:

```
@Component
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class PropertiesReloadJob implements Job {

    private static final Logger    LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PropertiesReloadJob.class);

    @Autowired
    private QuartzSchedulerService schedulerService;

    @Autowired
    private PropertiesService  propertiesService;

    public void loadAtStartup() {
        load();
        LOG.info("--- Registerting PropertiesReload Cron Job ---");
        schedulerService.registerCronJob(PropertiesReloadJob.class, propertiesService.getCacheReloadCronExpression());
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
        load();
        LOG.info("--- Updating Pro Cron Job ---");
        schedulerService.updateCronSchedule(PropertiesReloadJob.class, propertiesService.getCacheReloadCronExpression());
    }

    public void load(){
          // Load properties from DB
    }
```

The loadAtStartup() method is called during context initializtion and then after every 15 minutes the execute() method is called.

The cron expression used is: `0 0/15 * 1/1 * ? *`

Now, the problem is as follows:
Lets say that the job starts at 3:00:00, it will execute as many times it can till 3:00:01, rather than executing only once.

Next the job will start at 3:15:00 and again will run as many times it can till 3:15:01.

The number of times the job executes is different every time.

I am not sure what is causing this behaviour. I have tested the cron expression with cronmaker.

Can somebody point out the error here ?

Comment: Since the cron expression seems correct, I suppose your problem could depend on your job logic, have you tried with a different job? why are you rescheduling your job inside itself?

Comment: @davioooh No I haven't ..

Comment: Quick not - couldn't `0 0/15 * 1/1 * ? *` be simplified to `0 0/15 * * * ? *` - since the day-of-month increment is 1 day?

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup Yes it can be .. let me make this change. Also I started 2 tomcats, one has the code same as above while in another the reload does not update the cron schedule and problem is gone in the second one. This might mean that updating the cron schedule in the job itself is causing some kind of issue.

Comment: But I want to be able to make this change. How do I achieve this then ?

Comment: @sshntt I suppose rescheduling a job from inside itself could cause some "recursive disaster" :) so I think you need to create a separate job to make your checks and reschedule your main job inside it

Comment: I ran into a similar issue, maybe this will help, try this:

    `1 */15 * * * ? *`